# regex match as long as it comes before an optional character

Tags: regex

I currently have the regex `/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g` but I only want it to match as long as it comes before `.` iff `.` exists.

In other words `12345` can match. But `12345.6789` can't have matches after `.`

An easy workaround would be to make `if` `else` blocks breaking up the cases but I'd like it to it in a single regex

---

**More detail**

I'm working in javascript and making a regex to help me format numbers. Specifically, this regex will insert commas into numbers.

Currently this code works like this:

```
function formatter(myNum) {
   return myNum.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
}
```

Input 1: `12345.6789`
Output 1: `12,345.6,789`
Desired Output 1: `12,345.6789`

Input 2: `12345`
Desired Output 2: `12,345.6789`

Hopefully that clears up any confusion.

1. I want it to match when there is no `.`
2. If it does have a `.` it should be able to match before
3. I can make a simple work-around but it seems like regex should handle this easily?

Comment: It’s not clear exactly what you want. Please clarify by showing a few more input examples to illustrate what matches and what doesn’t. And make it clear if you want the entire input to match or only part of it.

Comment: To successfully skip decimals like this `123.456789` the regex engine type must be known.

Comment: @sln it's the one that came with js for me. How can I get you this info?

Comment: More complicated really. Only way I know is with PCRE `(?:(?:(?<!\d)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d*)*(?![.\d])|(?:\.\d*)+)(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|(?<=\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))` https://regex101.com/r/ZLdqtY/1

Comment: @sln the accepted answer does it.

Comment: Yeah, variable look behind will work if supported. There are other ways just using look ahead,  but its more involved. An important fact here is that `\B` is not appropriate. Need `(?<=\d)` as in `(?<=\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))`

Comment: So for example using `\B` matches between a5 as seen here https://regex101.com/r/ZYd7ji/1 . For reference, using `(?<=\d)` makes it work as it should like here https://regex101.com/r/9KgIIy/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use negative lookbehind with quantifiers (modern JS engines):

```js
function formatter(myNum) {
   return myNum.replace(/(?<!\.\d+)\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
}

console.log(formatter('1234512345'));
console.log(formatter('1234512345.1234512345'));
```

See compatibility:

- https://caniuse.com/?search=lookbehind
- https://node.green/#ES2018-features--RegExp-Lookbehind-Assertions